# Stop MBP switching to speakers (in Msft Teams) when Airpods Pro 2 taken out of ears

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, airpods

I like the automatic ear detection mode; it works really well 99% of the time.

However, there is one issue that's really starting to turn into a big annoyance. When I'm in a Microsoft Teams meeting and a colleague comes by my desk to ask a quick question, I take out the AirPods Pro 2 to answer. However, this causes the meeting audio to blast through the whole office from the MacBook speakers.

Thus, I was wondering if there are any options to disable this behavior? I want to keep the ear detection and do not want to disable it entirely. Although I don't think there's any scenario in which I'd want the audio to start blasting through the speakers as soon as I remove the Airpods from my ears.

I really appreciate any tips!

Comment: Use a wired set of headphones.

Comment: So you don't want to turn off automatic ear detection on your mac? Have you tried setting the audio output in teams to airpods instead of system?

Comment: @JBallin I am using the AirPods during the teams call. But if I take them out for a couple of seconds the sound immediately switches to the speakers which is super annoying to my coworkers. This doesn't happen with any other sound output like Spotify or YouTube. I was hoping that I could set some command-line flag to disable ear detection only in teams or something?